# I need to draw google custom search engine result and form in different div and allowOverwrite

Tags: google-custom-search

I want to display the google custom search engine in two different dom.

I know about the

and

But with this option I should be able to use
allow google.search.Csedr.addOverride("mysite_");

so the searchbox-only and searchresults-only didnot fulfill the purpose.

I tried with various option , like 
google.load('search', '1') and the rest as from documentation

And

```
            <script>
              (function() {
                var cx = '111111111111111111:111111';
                var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                gcse.async = true;
                gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
              })();
            </script>
```

with both this style I was failed to do the desired task.

I have use the google.setOnLoadCallback or window.__gcse both.But no  hope.Can any one help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution

```
            <!-- ON searchbox page actually header-->
            <div id="search">

                    <script>
                    function mycallBack(){
                        google.search.Csedr.addOverride("mysite_");

                    }
                    window.__gcse = {
                        callback : mycallBack
                    };
              (function() {
                var cx = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx:yyyyyyy';
                var gcse = document.createElement('script');
                gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
                gcse.async = true;
                gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                    '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
              })();
            </script>
            <gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
            <!-- Header end -->

            <!-- Result page start -->
            <div style="display:none"><!-- Return the unescaped result URL.-->
            <div id="mysite_webResult">
            <div class="gs-webResult gs-result" data-vars="{longUrl:function() {
                      var i = unescapedUrl.indexOf(visibleUrl);
                      return i &lt; 1 ? visibleUrl : unescapedUrl.substring(i);}}"><!-- Build the result data structure.-->
            <table cellspacing="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="margin-left:30px;" valign="top"><a class="gs-title" data-attr="{href:unescapedUrl,target:target}" data-elif="typeof title !== 'undefined'" style="text-decoration:none !important;"> <img data-attr="{src:richSnippet.product.image, width:160, height:120}" data-if="typeof richSnippet !== 'undefined' &amp;&amp; typeof richSnippet.product !== 'undefined' &amp;&amp; typeof richSnippet.product.image !== 'undefined'" /> <img data-attr="{src:richSnippet.cseImage.src,  width:160, height:120}" data-elif="typeof richSnippet !== 'undefined' &amp;&amp; typeof richSnippet.cseImage !== 'undefined' &amp;&amp; typeof richSnippet.cseImage.src !== 'undefined'" /> </a></td>
                        <td style="width:40px;"></td>
                        <td valign="top"><!-- Append results within the table cell.-->
                        <div class="gs-title" style="text-decoration:none; font-family:'ubuntu' sans-sertif;">  </div>

                        <div class="gs-snippet" data-body="html(content)" style="margin-bottom:30px;"></div>

                        <div data-if="Vars.richSnippet &amp;&amp; typeof richSnippet.product !== 'undefined' &amp;&amp; richSnippet.product.productid" style="color:#676767"><span class="gs-product-code-label" style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;color:black;">Product code: &nbsp; &nbsp;</span></div>

                        <div data-if="Vars.richSnippet &amp;&amp; typeof richSnippet.product !== 'undefined' &amp;&amp; richSnippet.product.oepartnumber" style="color:#676767"><span class="gs-oeproduct-code-label" style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;color:black;">OE Part Numbers: &nbsp; &nbsp;</span></div>

                        <div data-if="Vars.richSnippet &amp;&amp; typeof richSnippet.offer !== 'undefined' &amp;&amp; richSnippet.offer.price" style="color:#676767"><span class="gs-offer-price-label" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:red;">&pound;</span></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <gcse:searchresults-only></gcse:searchresults-only>
            <!-- Result page end -->
```